# Git Bash gives error spark-class line 96: CMD: bad array subscript

Tags: pyspark, git-bash

I have been trying to get pyspark to work but as soon as I installed it, I tried to run spark-shell and it gave me an error. I installed java using this code `conda install -c conda-forge openjdk=11` and then tried to install pyspark using `pip install pyspark==3`. I did create a spark environment on it's own to be able to do it but this is the error message when I try to run `spark-shell`.

```
C:\Users\Jonathan\anaconda3\envs\spark-env/Library\bin\java -cp "C:\Users\Jonathan\anaconda3\envs\spark-env\lib\site-packages\pyspark/conf;C:\Users\Jonathan\anaconda3\envs\spark-env\lib\site-packages\pyspark\jars\*" "-Dscala.usejavacp=true" -Xmx1g org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit --class org.apache.spark.repl.Main --name "Spark shell" spark-shell
C:\Users\Jonathan\anaconda3\envs\spark-env\lib\site-packages\pyspark/bin/spark-class: line 96: CMD: bad array subscript
```

How can I fix this? because I have tried uninstalling pyspark and uninstalling openjdk and reinstalling both of them but it didn't work at all. Oh, also, I am using a Windows PC with Windows 11. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any solution here Jon?

Comment: So far, no solution has been found.